# Pandas-InnerJoin- Multiplication of Rows

Tags: python, pandas, inner-join

I have two sets of data, with one common column. Some rows have repetitions so I created a similar small example.

Here are my dataframes:

```
#Dataframe1
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10], ['tom', 11], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

#Dataframe2
 
data2 = [['tom', 'LA'], ['tom', 'AU'], ['nick', 'NY'], ['juli', 'London']]
 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Name', 'City'])

#InnerJoin

a = pd.merge(df, df2, how= 'inner', on = 'Name')
a
```

The result is:[image]

So, Instead of 2 rows with Tom, we have 4 rows. How can I solve this issue?

Thank you,

Comment: The four rows with `Name=tom` are expected because the join key, `Name`, has duplicate values to begin with. Which row(s) from `df2` do you need joined onto the `Name=tom` rows in `df`? If you know that corresponding rows in each DataFrame are aligned, you could try `a = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary key for duplicate name in order, such that the first Tom in df joins to the first Tom in df2 and 2nd Tom joins to 2nd Tom in df2, etc.

```
df = df.assign(name_key = df.groupby('Name').cumcount())
df2 = df2.assign(name_key = df.groupby('Name').cumcount())

df.merge(df2, how='inner', on=['Name', 'name_key'])
```

Output:

```
   Name  Age  name_key    City
0   tom   10         0      LA
1   tom   11         1      AU
2  nick   15         0      NY
3  juli   14         0  London
```